# ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device (errno=19)

Tags: kali-linux, vpn, openvpn, tunneling

I'm helpless.
I uninstalled openvpn, I did a lot of things but nothing.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `sudo modprobe tun`.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what the problem is here: in what context are you getting this error? Are you trying to *install* openvpn? You mentioned that you *un-* installed it, but not why.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i had my openvpn files, so i run sudo openvpn <file.ovpn> and i have the error.

Comment: im not really sure that my wsl 2 is set up, because a simple command like "wsl -l -v" didnt work.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting. Also, when asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information.